# What should we do with users who ask for upvotes and to accept their answers?

Tags: discussion, users, behavior

I'm not a moderator, but I recently stumbled into a user whose behaviour isn't the most correct (or so I believe).

For each answer he gives, he asks for upvotes and for the OP to "accept his answer please" and "upvote me now".

As a regular (non-moderator) user, is there anything I can do about it other than to address him in comments, pointing out the bad behaviour?

Comment: You mean besides the systems of flagging and downvoting which are already in place?

Comment: Flag the comments, or flag a post by the user for moderator attention. Meta users cannot do all that much about this behaviour, but moderators *can*.

Comment: Yes @Gimby, besides that. I don't want to go through all his posts, answers, comments, and search for every plead for upvotes. I can see a pattern and I was looking for a way of doing something other than flagging and downvoting as they seem as I'm doing it for individual posts. For example, If I make an unacceptable comment, it shoud be downvoted but if I do that as a rule, something else should be done. If I find ten of his bad comments and flag them, I may still miss all his other posts that should be flagged. Can you see my point?

Comment: Then flag one, include in the custom message a few links to more and a mention that you see this as a pattern of behaviour - the mods can then investigate that using the tools at their disposal. Tracking down and flagging every comment is unnecessary.

Comment: It's generally considered poor etiquette to single out a particular user on Meta... Mostly because of the risk of the user becoming a target. It would have been better to just describe the behavior.

Comment: I faced a worse situation, In which an OP asked me to upvote his **question**!

Comment: Is this really the wording ("upvote me now")? I use similar instructions, a bit more polite, when I answer new user's questions (rep<100, answer 1 day old and question not active).

Comment: While I completely agree with you, sometimes I stumble into anew user that ask something and likes my answer (i.e. he comments the answer: Thanks! that worked perfectly!") but they dont accept the answer itself. This is generally because they just dont understand how SO works. I believe that in those cases, asking the asker to accept the asnwer is proper practice, as one is teaching them how to use SO, not asking them for rep. I sometimes do this, in both mine and other users answers, whenever it is clear that the answer is what the OP wanted.

Comment: There is a persistent troll who has been doing this for many years. Another reason to flag.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You have two options:

- Flag the comments as *No longer needed*; badgering for votes, bounties and accepts<sup>*</sup> is not what comments are meant for.
- If there is a widespread pattern, flag one of posts by the user illustrating the problem, and explain the pattern in a *in need of moderator intervention* message.

Moderators have the tools to handle cases like these. I've handled this case, there is no need to flag this user anymore.

---

<sup>*</sup> Teaching *new users* how accepting works is fine. If you posted an answer, the user gives you a hearty *thanks!* comment and it turns out they are pretty new and never accepted an answer before, feel free to show them how accepting works. Personally I use

> Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 18):

Read the "general expected behaviour policy" and shot down my intended answer of "This behavior is annoying and unpleasant, but not wrong. Could you please upvote and accept this post?"