# Dealing with inline tantrums from users whose answers weren't accepted

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

What do we do about answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/32910988/128421 ([<10k screenshot of the edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Bp8.png)) where the poster is obviously trying to strike out at the OP using passive/aggressive tactics, resulting in visual noise the rest of us "get" to see?  This particular user does this very often, and because he's fairly prolific, it results in many such cow-patties lying about.

I consider the source and try to move on, but it's irritating to move into a question and stumble upon such a tantrum.

Comment: Only those with 10k rep count as "the rest of us" here; even the asker can't see it.

Comment: hmm... i expected to see a low rep user, not someone with 82k rep... where's the disconnect

Comment: Were there deleted comments? Why does he say the OP hates it? I'm so confused! But that definitely is unacceptable behavior. Especially for someone with such experience on SO

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a meta post about this user before. I'd be surprised if another mod hasn't spoken to them about this yet.

Comment: Not exactly the first time, either: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32896483/19679 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/32838917/19679 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/32796095/19679 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/32787939/19679 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/32746328/19679

Comment: @BoltClock - You might be thinking of this similar case: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288242/19679

Comment: Can one of you pass me the diamond for just a few minutes? I'll take care of it

Comment: @codeMagic: Way ahead of you, sorry.

Comment: @codeMagic better luck next election.

Comment: @BoltClock damn! Well, keep me in mind for next time :P

Comment: @ryanyuyu haha....thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @Josh Caswell: If it were on a smaller site, sure, it's not that big of a deal. But this is SO. There are more 10k-rep users on SO than *there are users* in some sites.

Comment: Y'all, Thanks for the comments. I forgot about the aspect that the changes and deletions are affecting community resources; That they're being defaced with noisome graffiti prior to deletion was what has irked me.

Comment: @sawa If you think you write a good answer, don't only think about the OP. You might help someone in the future, which will be pleased that you wrote that answer and helped him!

Comment: IMO, the point system is almost a distraction or disservice to the community sometimes. Some completely miss the fact that we're here to help others succeed, not to gain points, which in the scheme of things are entirely worthless since I can't even buy a cup of tea to sip with the points while working on questions. I answer questions and clean up the site because it helps other learn. I spent years learning from others, so now it's time for me to give back. Points are a curiosity but creating good answers and making things clear are satisfying.

Comment: @theTinMan: The points system is supposed to be an indicator of goodness. So if you're getting downvotes, perhaps you're not helping others as much as you think you are.

Comment: September 16 is curious on the Reputation list for that user.

Comment: @BillWoodger Because it's higher than 200? Can be any number of things. Accepted answers, accepting answers, bonuses, reversal of serial downvotes etc.

Comment: @MrLister No, I meant the apparent serial upvoting of a load of questions, timed earlier than all the other upvotes, but not counting for anything. Don't know how it works that way around, plus the irony of serial-upvoting "after" reaching the rep-cap.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I VERY seldom get down votes, so that's not a concern to me.

Comment: @theTinMan: Your point was ostensibly about the community, not just yourself.

Comment: It was difficult to tell who the subject was in your comment. "you" and "you're" are not very explicit.

Comment: The linked answer has been voted to be undeleted, and is now getting serial downvotes. Are the voters stupid people who directly follow the link after reading this question just to downvote it without reading, or are they super-clever, and have a way better answer (which they do not want to share)? It is contradictory that an answer that was good enough to be voted to be undeleted is receiving negative points. If you are editing/undeleting, at the same time, you have to deal with these guys.

Comment: @sawa I can understand that you're frustrated and angry about the downvotes that you received on your deleted/undeleted/deleted answer, but calling people stupid isn't helping *anyone*, especially not you, nor is repeating the same message 3 times in a row in the comments to the people involved. **Flag your post for moderator attention** instead.

Comment: @Cupcake The reason I had to post the same post three times is because addressing a user using the `@` mark is allowed by the system for only single person per comment.

Comment: @Cupcake: Monday, thank you :) Removing my last two comments, I've probably wasted enough time on this myself.

Comment: Is the person aware his deleted posts can be seen? The tantrum might in its intent very well be equal to punching a wall.

Comment: Whatever the motivation, it's still undesirable.

Comment: @theTinMan: I missed your comment; please use at-notification syntax to ping people in comment replies.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is a very good reason users with 10k reputation gain the ability to see deleted posts. If a post was deleted *for* being low quality, off-topic, or abusive, that's all and well and dandy: you have access to the content of a post, and the circumstances leading up to its fate, and you can even vote to restore it if you feel it was wrongfully deleted. These are normal and part of a moderator's daily life.

But if someone is lashing out *through* deleted posts, then they're basically asking to get into trouble with the people who will see them. After all, if you're leaving notes on your deleted posts explaining the reason for deletion then clearly you want them to be seen. There's nothing stopping you from doing that, but if you're going to do it, make sure you have a constructive explanation (at least one that can't already be surmised via contextual clues); otherwise, don't. It's the same principle as when you're about to respond to someone in a comment. If you can't do it without calling them names, please don't bother.

I've notified the user and asked them to stop with their personal remarks. If the existing posts bother you, you have the ability to remove the editorial remarks. If you see them doing this again, or they decide to roll back your changes, feel free to flag the deleted post for our attention.

On the other hand, if you'd rather not have to deal with rollback wars, the next best alternative is to ignore them. While this is annoying, we *are* talking about posts that have already been deleted after all. There are far more pressing issues on the site than these.

---

Just to be clear: if someone is replacing the content of a deleted post with ellipses or some form of blanking out the content, *that's fine*, especially if the post is long, in which case they're just trying to be considerate rather than make you scroll through the entire thing. Or if they're embarrassed, that's fine too. If the post wasn't edited and deleted within the 5-minute grace period you can see the original content by looking at the revision history anyway.

After all, the system does exactly the same thing with deleted posts that were flagged spam/offensive...

Comment: It wasn't just leaving remarks in deleted answers. I actually saw a *comment* along the lines of "*This answer will be deleted if the OP doesn't like it*" on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32896483/19679) (which has now been removed). Such passive-aggressive comments shouldn't be left on one's answers either, because it's like begging for upvotes; the OP may feel pressured into accepting/upvoting the answer, when they otherwise would not have been.

Comment: @Cupcake I have frequently seen comments by other users that actually beg for acceptance along the lines of "*Please accept this answer if you think it helped you*". And such comments are not claimed to be a problem? Unlike these users, I do not beg for upvote/acceptance. I just gave them a notification (and choices).

Comment: @sawa: Er, [they are](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297597/what-to-do-with-user-asking-for-upvote-and-accept)...? You're not begging, but as Cupcake has said, you're manipulating the OP into accepting your answer otherwise the community risks losing a potentially valuable answer all because of one inaction from one poor sap. Taken to extremes it could even be seen as making threats (not threats of violence or anything, but *threats nonetheless*). That's even *worse* than begging.

Comment: @sawa I consider comments like "Please accept this answer if you think it helped you" perfectly acceptable *if and only if* the OP is new on the site - new users usually don't know their way around SO, and asking them to accept the answer that solved their problem is just part of their education (I've done this myself a couple of times).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt personally, I'm very cautious about leaving comments like that. I only mention things like that to a beginner OP if they've already left a comment on an answer that said that it helped them, and then didn't upvote or accept it after like a day or two.

Comment: I think I once deleted a post, first adding something to the effect of, _"Deleted out of deference to <some other, better answer>."_ I guess that counts as a 10k easter egg. :/

Comment: @canon: Make that :/ a :)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt actually, I thought about this, and I've got an even better method of handling something like that. Leave a comment on the OP's question instead, along the lines of "*Don't forget to upvote any answers that you found helpful*" (adjust for accepting answers as needed), instead of pointing out *your answer* specifically by leaving a comment on it instead of the question. That way you influence the OP's decisions *even less* as to whether or not they upvote/accept your answer, while still teaching them how to use the site.

Comment: Agreed, @Cupcake.

Comment: @Cupcake That sounds sensible - I think I'm going to steal that :-) Do you also suggest that they accept the answer they found most helpful?