# Is it a good thing to accept an answer to a question if it help but didn't answer the question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I had this question that was not solved and someone posted a comment to make my code simpler, but it didn't answer my question.

Some comments later, people told me to accept an answer based on the fact that I used the commented code. My point is that I don't want to accept an answer if it didn't answer my question. If someone is looking for an answer to the same question that I had and start reading my question in hope to find an answer (while there's not) I think it will only waste some time to someone without answering the question.

Comment: You don't have to listen to people telling you to accept an answer. They aren't supposed to do that. It's fine if they are just informing you that you _can_, because some new users don't know, but whether or not you do it is up to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please flag comments requesting you to accept an answer as “no longer needed”. Moderators will gladly remove them. In the best case, these comments are just noise. In the worst case, they can be downright bullying.

Don’t let anyone pressure you into accepting an answer. As the asker of a question, it is your decision alone which answer to accept—or even *whether* to accept an answer. If you are not yet satisfied, you are entirely within your rights (I’d even say *advisable*) not to accept any of the answers.

You can, of course, still upvote answers that you found helpful (perhaps they offered a partial solution). But don’t feel pressured to upvote answers, either, if you didn’t find them helpful.

Comment: But are there *some* circumstances where "suggesting an accept" is acceptable, as indicated by Martijn, [here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297598/10871073)? (I've used this approach, occasionally, for new users who have no history of accepting.)

Comment: That is not in itself a problem, @Adrian, which is why I don't recommend using "unkind or unfriendly" flags, since comments teaching new users about how accepting answers works *may* be innocuous. However, I will still delete those comments on sight in response to "no longer needed" flags. Once they're flagged, they're no longer needed. Either because the answer has been accepted, or because the asker has had a chance to see the comment but decided not to accept the answer anyway. By the way, the Help Center has a page on accepting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer