# flagging comments that invite to accept the answer, am I doing right?

Tags: support, comments, accepted-answer, comment-flags

I noticed that a user writes in most of the questions he replies the following comment:

> If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer (click on
> the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to
> filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members.

I flagged some of these comments as "It's no longer needed" but after I thought:

Am I right to flag these comments?

Is this kind of behavior (asking for the OP to accept the answer) allowed on Stack Overflow?

Comment: The only case where this is really excusable is when the OP is a new poster. Even then it's should be used sparingly, it just adds clutter.

Comment: @zcoop98 Some users do it on every single Question they answer. I've seen it too. The problem is that it seems to work for them. Even if there is a better other Answer, theirs seems to be accepted.

Comment: @Scratte meh, a simple NLN flag is all that is needed. flag, move on, it'll get deleted. doesn't really matter that they keep doing it, someone always will

Comment: thanks for your comments and to who linked the previous questions, I did a search but didn't find one specific to flagging, however some of the answers there provide the instructions

Comment: @KevinB That is not what I found. How do you think I came to see that they do it on every Question? (Please note that I cannot see deleted comments ;-)

Comment: flag one and see. It may take a bit for it to go away, but it will

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I can flag one.. and then that will go away. The rest will not.

Comment: so flag the rest too

Comment: @KevinB You mean I should "follow" a user and flag their comments? Or go through all their Answers and meticulously flag all 459 Questions where they left a comment? Sorry, that's just not a good use of my time.

Comment: @Scratte Then we are in agreement, ;)

Comment: The task being unsolvable by one person's actions isn't reason to not still take the actions you can.

Comment: @KevinB No we are not. There should be another way of handling this than a NLN flag on comments one by one, as you suggested. I find your suggesting to be quite poor. And in combination with your "meh", I'm thinking you're accepting this behaviour.

Comment: @Scratte So make a feature request suggesting a solution.

Comment: You're awfully inventive in what I "should do". I don't think this needs a feature request at all. I'd think there was another way to handle it already.

Comment: like... [raising a flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297598/400654) ;)

Comment: like my answers says ijn one of the dupe, as long it is to remind the user how the side works, it is ok

Comment: I used to leave such comments.... hopefully you didn't find one of my old comments. That being said, it's _okay_, to a limit. If the OP says, "This helped me!", then it's okay to ask them to accept your answer. On smaller tags there tends to be one answer per question. So it's fine.